# How to toggle based on saved radio button selections using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that the user can save and return to edit. I have questions on the form that toggle a div based on the user's answer to a previous question. There are multiple of these question types.  If the answer is 'yes', the div for that question should display.

Currently, the divs are displaying on the form load, when they should be hidden.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BbrwT/14/ (I setup example so question one has not been answered yet, where question two has been answered 'no')

```
<div>
    <label>Select #1:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" class="toggle" value="1">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" class="toggle" value="0">No
</div>

<div id="details">
   Details #1
</div>

<div>
    <label>Select #2:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" class="toggle" value="1">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" class="toggle" value="0" checked="checked">No
</div>

<div id="details">
   Details #2
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($('.toggle:checked').val() != 1){
        $(this).parent().next('#details').hide()
    }

    $('.toggle').on('change',function(){

        var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;

        $(this).parent().next('#details').toggle(showOrHide);

    })  

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you could chain the `change` method on to your `change` handler -

```
$('.toggle').on('change',function(){

    var showOrHide = false;

    $(this).siblings('input[type=radio]').andSelf().each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 1 && $(this).prop("checked")) showOrHide = true;
    })    

    $(this).parent().next('#details').toggle(showOrHide);

}).change()
```

That should call the `change` method on loading the page and hide anything that your logic states should be hidden. I've also changed logic slightly so the values of sibling radio buttons are also checked.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/sBErV/2/

Comment: That's close.  The only issue is that if one of the options is selected 'yes', the div should be visible when the form is loaded.  See http://jsfiddle.net/58xqM/2/

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working as the Select #2 is marked as 'yes', but the div is still hidden when the page loads.

Comment: Sorry - pasted the wrong link, should have been - http://jsfiddle.net/58xqM/6/. Hope that works!

Comment: @irpr101 quick question, why does it break if i change the first option to 'no' and second option to 'yes'.  http://jsfiddle.net/58xqM/7/  how would the jquery change if this were the case?

Comment: Got it close: http://jsfiddle.net/58xqM/8/ but now it doesn't work if the question is 'unanswered' http://jsfiddle.net/58xqM/9/

Comment: @Michael I've updated the answer and linked to a new fiddle, I think it might be right this time!

Comment: Excellent! Sorry it took so long!

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively simple approach to hide the div following a div that contains an `input` of `value="0"` that's also `checked`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div:has("input[value=0]:checked")').next('div').hide();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BbrwT/15/).

Please note that you've got two elements sharing the same `id`. This is ***invalid*** according to the html spec:

id = name [case-sensitive]

This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

---

Updated, with a slightly improved approach:

```
function showHide(){
    $('div:has("input:radio[value=0]:checked")').next('div').hide();
    $('div:has("input:radio[value=1]:checked")').next('div').show();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    showHide();
    $('input:radio').change(
        function(){
            showHide();
        });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BbrwT/17/).